# MYSQL query to Django

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

Hi guys I want to get this query in Django and cant seem to get the results I want

```
SELECT DISTINCT herramienta_id,sum(cantidad)    
FROM inventario_transaccion 
WHERE 
    carrito_id = 1 and herramienta_id = 1;
```

this query return in MYSQL Workbench

```
herramienta_id  cantidad
+--------------+---------+
|       1      |    5    |
+--------------+---------+
```

What I'm trying to do is get all tools with carrito_id = pk , and get all distinct values and sum the cantidad of each

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `GROUP BY` instead of a `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Thanks i will try with group_by . I'm sort of new to programming and mysql

Comment: You probably want something like `SELECT herramienta_id, SUM(cantidad) FROM inventario_transaccion WHERE carrito_id=1 GROUP BY herramienta_id`

Comment: Thanks. Will try

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your Django Models, so I can only guess, but "in Django" it should be something like this.

```
Herramienta.objects\
    .filter(carrito_id=pk)\
    .aggregate(cantidad=Count('inventario_transaccion'))
```

That is, assuming that "inventario_transaccion" is the reverse `name` on a foreign key from another Model.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working latter that night and I used the following :
`cantidades = Transaccion.objects.values('herramienta__description').annotate(Sum('cantidad')).filter(activo=True, carrito_id=pk)`